# Supremum, limit and limsup

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum, epsilon-delta, limsup-and-liminf

> Let {$a_n$} and {$b_n$} be two sequences of real numbers such that {$b_n$}
> converges to L. It is known that the supremum S of the set {$a_n$: n $\in$ N}
> exists and is not equal to any of the $a_j$'s.
> Define the sequence {$c_n$}
> by $c_n$ = $a_n$ + $b_n$ for each n $\in$ N. Prove that $\limsup_{x\to∞}$ $c_n$ = S + L .

I encountered this problem from an analysis course. I tried to use the fact that $b_n$, a converging sequence, is bounded and since $b_n$ is a real sequence, it has supremum S. Next,

Since $c_n$ = $a_n$ + $b_n$, $b_n < L$ and $a_n < S$

${c_n} < L + S$.

However, I cannot prove that L + S is the supremum of $c_n$.

Comment: The supremum of $b_n$ may be bigger than its limit $L$.

Comment: It is not supremum but limit superior you are asked. Limit superior is more complicated than supremum, so I recommend you to review its definition carefully so that you understand how limit superior is different from supremum or limit.